# In QFT, how does the polarization of a photon affect whether it will be absorbed by a horizontally, vertically, or longitudinally oriented filter?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Classically it is explained by E and B fields.
However, my question is in QFT where the polarization of a photon is encoded as a vector (left or right handed in the direction of motion; in other words +1 or -1): how does the polarization (or a superposition of polarizations such as linearly polarized) of a single photon affect the probability of whether it will be absorbed by a horizontally, vertically, or longitudinally oriented filter?

guess: is it related to the fact that only left but not right handed spin-1 particles can flip the spin of an electron (half spin) causing a net up or down-ness of the electron particular directions along the wire. Or does this not happen or have little impact.

Comment: The usual polarization states in introductory QFT texts have definite helicity, meaning they correspond to circularly polarized waves. Such waves are an equal superposition of two perpendicular linear polarizations, so they always have a 50% chance of being blocked by a polarizing filter.

Comment: Have you seen an experiment performed well outside the classical regime where these filters still absorbed photons according to their polarizations? If not, then the answer is again E and B fields.

Comment: agreed I think the answer is E and B fields:  the electromagnetic lagrangian density (made up of A_u) and it's component electromagnetic field strength tensor $F_{\mu\nu}$ has $F_{0i}$ as the component representing the electric field, in other words the tensor encodes the orientation and possible resulting orientations and my toy view in the question is too simple without carrying out a full solution (which we know will match the classical equations).

Comment: I doubt that flipping electron spins is the correct explanation for the work of a classical polarizer, but I would refer to a quantum optics/solid state physics textbook or article that deals with that problem explicitly. My intuition tells me that one will have to deal with many-particle states similar to the problem of absorption band spectra of solids. Just my two cents. I might be wrong.